# Switch on WAN for connecting two routers

Tags: networking

I am fairly new to network engineering, to be clear, I am not researching it much, it's not what I am most interested in, but sometimes you need to find solution to problems in fields, where you would otherwise not go. So, my problem is I think fairly easy, in my house, we have one network (WAN) input cable, currently it's connected directly to our router, but I want to connect second router to have second network, that would be besides our main network. But since we have only one cable I was thinking of placing switch directly on to the WAN cable and just connecting to routers after it, so they would on same like level from outside. Is this possible ? How else can I do it ?

Thanks in advance

P.S. Asked already on network engineering, but it's off-topic there and I was recommended to post it here

Comment: The issue here is you are thinking consumer home networking, like Walmart/Bestbuy consumer grade routers. In this case the best bet would be to move up to a small business router than have have multiple networks, ZyXEL, Ubiquiti, or similar, and have one internet connection to the router, and two distinct networks on the LAN side... Maybe port 1 is 192.168.1.0/24 and port 2 is 192.168.2.0/24 and then connect the things you want behind that.

Comment: The problem is most ISP's will not allow you more than one WAN connection in a home/consumer setup, connecting a second router either will not work or will break the connection of the first router. That said, some ISP's have no problem with this either, only testing it will tell you.

Comment: @acejavelin sorry for late response on your comment, but I find it like best solution, we have asus AC-68U, pretty old router, do you think it can do it ? Or will we need to switch up router for that ? if so, what router would you recommend ?

Comment: Before what get into that, WHY do you need second router or network? What problem are you trying to fix with this configuration?

Comment: @acejavelin Well, to be clear, I want to add raspberry pi with server hosting, that also works as router, but I don't want it to add it to my main network, since it needs some port-forwarding and it increases risks of my network getting hacked (maybe a little to paranoid, but hey). I thought that it's not much difference of what I add after, but it may be...

Answer (score 0):

Routers connect networks, so you need a router on the border between you and your internet provider. A switch before the router would split the link, and this might not be what your internet provider allows you to do. You can however have many routers on your side of the border router. Each router creates a separate network, so with two routers, you'd have a big local network and the second one inside the big one.

Comment: So you are saying, that I've put a third router before my two router (just put router intead of the switch there) it will work ? But what if I will want to make some ports on some device inside one network open  (port forwarding) than I will need to port-forward on the inside and outside router ? and what about security, if one network gets hacked into ?

Comment: @literally_no_one Yes, if you put a router there, it will be your first router. Then you can add routers inside. And yes, you need to cascade forwards on routers - if that's what you want. But you don't need forwards inside networks, as devices can see each other there. Always think about connection in terms of who can speak to whom and who needs a proxy - or a number of them. Security-wise, each router is a security border. How you manage it is another story.

Comment: This seems like an over-complicated solution for a simple problem. A simple small business router that allows multiple networks, or even an older router that supports OpenWRT or similar firmware, could handle this with ONE router only.

Comment: @acejavelin Isn't your comment subjective? The question is about adding the second router. OpenWRT can be much more difficult than just adding a second router. Which might already be available for use - as opposed to a new router that still needs to be bought. Which in turn requires a few decisions and research.

Comment: Well, to be clear, I want to add raspberry pi with server hosting, that also works as router, but I don't want it to add it to my main network, since it needs some port-forwarding and it increases risks of my network getting hacked (maybe a little to paranoid, but hey). I thought that it's not much difference of what I add after, but it may be....

Comment: @literally_no_one So you want your RPi be reachable from the Internet?

Comment: @tom463 yes, but I don't want it inside my main network

Comment: @literally_no_one Do you even have a public IP?

Comment: Yes, we have public static IP, it's possible to do it, if I've setup port-forwarding, but I don't want that, since I am scared of getting hacked, that's why I don't want it inside my main network.

Comment: @literally_no_one Then either you put your main network on a separate ISP IP (if that's allowed, and it doesn't have to be public) and use the public static for the Pi - the switch scenario applies here, or you have to push your main network deeper on your side: main router splitting a) to the Pi b) to your main network. Thus they would be separated. But Pi will have to reside within your "supernetwork" nevertheless.